# .htaccess mod_rewrite rules work independently but not together

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am trying to set some url rewrites in .htaccess.

The first is to redirect urls with language codes (site is now in one language):

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

========================

The Second is to be more descriptive for for seo purposes:

/community/

to

/tutors-and-students/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/community.*$
RewriteRule .*  /tutors-and-students    [L,R=301,DPI]
```

=================================

The third changes profile urls:

/community/myprofile/username

to

/tutors-and-students/username

```
RedirectMatch permanent myprofile(.*) http://www.profr.org/tutors-and-students/$1
```

=========================

They all work independently but not together as:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/community.*$
RewriteRule .*  /tutors-and-students    [L,R=301,DPI]
RedirectMatch permanent myprofile(.*) http://www.profr.org/tutors-and-students/$1
```

Grateful for your tips.

Comment: When you say not working what problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: The last rule does nothing to redirect urls with /myprofile/ in this example

Comment: Try using  a new browser to test.

Comment: In this directory did you place above .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should just stick with mod_rewrite as opposed to mixing it together with redirects from mod_alias:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^.*/?community /tutors-and-students [L,R=301,DPI]

RewriteRule ^.*/?myprofile(.*)$ /tutors-and-students/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: hm - that didn't quite crack it. webmaster tools is telling me I have 404 urls like this: /en/community/myprofile/1565-joshua-oganga which when should redirect to /tutors-and-students/1565-joshua-oganga. Instead it is going to /tutors-and-students. Any thoughts?

Comment: @larpo you need to flip the "community" and "myprofile" rules, since the community one is matching /en/**community**/myprofile/1565-joshua-oganga first. But I guess what you meant with community is only **this** URL? `/en/community`? Then change the community regex to: `^.*/?community/?$`

Comment: thanks - this url still doesn't work - it's 404 - /community/822-ratna-ventrapragada - the conditions now are: RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^.*/?myprofile(.*)$ /tutors-and-students/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^.*/?community/?$ /tutors-and-students [L,R=301,DPI]